# Guardar / Enviar información ArrayList de objetos en Intent a Activity

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de guardar datos como un `ArrayList` para una app multiactividad, me muevo a través de varias actividades y volviendo de unas a otras, manejo varios `ArrayList` y me gustaría saber si puedo almacenar esos ArrayList sin necesidad de estar pasandolos constantemente con Bundles e Intents entre las actividades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes realizarlo mediante 2 metodos:

#### Enviar ArrayList entre Activities.

Pero definitivamente la forma ideal es enviar los datos entre Activities a travez del `bundle`.

Donde **tu objeto debe implementar  la clase `Serializable` o `Parcelable`:**

```
public class Dato implements Serializable {
```

Enviarias un ArrayList de objetos en el Intent mediante `.putExtra()`:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SegundaActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("listaDatos", listaDatos);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Para recibir el ArrayList en la Activity destino, se realiza de esta forma:

```
ArrayList<tipoObjeto> listaDatos = (ArrayList<tipoObjeto> ) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("listaDatos");
```

---

#### Guardar ArrayList en preferencias.

Puedes guardar los datos en un [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

```
SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences( "mispreferencias", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    editor = settings.edit();
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    set.addAll(listaDatos);
    editor.putStringSet("key", set);
    editor.commit();
```

y obtenerlos de esta forma:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("mispreferencias", MODE_PRIVATE);
Set<String> set = preferences.getStringSet("key", null);
```

Answer (score 2):

Pues actualmente lo hago creando una clase Abstracta con valores estaticos y extendiendo las actividades a ella .

```
   public abstract class Miclase extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static String valor="hola";


}
   public class AlgunaActivity extends Miclase {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Log.d("test", String.valueOf(valor));
    }
}
```

Asi obtendrias acceso a todos los valores o metodos que quieras. Solo escribiendolos sobre el Activity que quieras una vez ya extendido, 
esa es una manera que realmente no se si sea lo mas propio.

Otra forma es con [Preferencias Compartidas / Shared Preferences](http://www.sgoliver.net/blog/preferencias-en-android-i-shared-preferences/)
Alli podras leer del tema. Lo cual creo mas propio que la primera.

Answer (score 0):

Lo pude realizar de la siguiente forma, enviando primero la lista

```
Intent intencion = new
Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity2.class);
intencion.putExtra("lista",personas(cargarDatos()));
startActivity(intencion);
```

y lo recibe como:

`ArrayList<Persona> listaPersona;
listaPersona = (ArrayList<Persona>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("lista");`