# Cómo utilizar un modelo en varias activity

Tags: java, android

Mi modelo:

```
public class model_Frio {
    String tarima,grados;
    public String getTarima() {
        return tarima;
    }

    public void setTarima(String tarima) {
        this.tarima = tarima;
    }

    public String getGrados() {
        return grados;
    }

    public void setGrados(String grados) {
        this.grados = grados;
    }
}
```

Activity de guardar:

```
model_Frio model_frio;
model_frio = new model_Frio();

model_frio.setGrados(grados.getText().toString());
```

Mi problema es que el activity que guarda esa información necesito cerrarlo para desde otro activity recoger esa información:

```
model_Frio model_frio;
model_frio = new model_Frio();
Log.d("datos>",model_frio.getgrados());
```

Pero recibo el siguiente error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: desarrolladoresalpha.adminempaq, PID: 18129
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{desarrolladoresalpha.adminempaq/desarrolladoresalpha.adminempaq.Tarimas_App}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2193)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2243)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
      at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
      at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:139)
      at desarrolladoresalpha.adminempaq.Tarimas_App.onCreate(Tarimas_App.java:33)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2157)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2243) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5019) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2):

Primeramente el error aquí :

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message

es debido a que necesitas formatear correctamente el mensaje en el `LogCat`, y el valor que deseas imprimir, `model_frio.getgrados()`, tiene valor null lo cual no es correcto:

```
Log.d("datos>",model_frio.getgrados());
```

puedes convertir el valor a String para evitar este problema:

```
Log.d("datos>", String.valueOf(model_frio.getgrados()));
```

---

**Lo que deseas de acuerdo a tu pregunta es enviar [Enviar `ArrayList` entre `Activities`.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64925/guardar-enviar-informaci%C3%B3n-arraylist-en-intent-a-activity)**

Pero definitivamente la forma ideal es enviar los datos entre Activities a travez del `bundle`.

Donde tu objeto debe implementar  la clase `Serializable`:

```
public class model_Frio implements Serializable {
```

Enviarías un `ArrayList` de objetos entre `Activities`, esto se realiza agregando los datos en el Intent mediante `.putExtra()`:

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SegundaActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("listaDatos", listaDatos);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Para recibir el ArrayList en la Activity destino, se realiza de esta forma:

```
ArrayList<model_Frio> listaDatos = (ArrayList<model_Frio> ) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("listaDatos");
```