# Como pasar una ArrayList de una activity a otro activity?

Tags: android-studio, arraylist

Estoy haciendo un proyecto `Android Studio` y llegue a un punto donde debo enviar un `ArrayList` que almacena todos los ítems seleccionados `(String,String,int)` a otro `Activity`, e intentado utilizar el `intent` pero me sale un error de que debo parsear el `Arraylist`. ¿Alguien sabe como mandarlo?

**Activity Principal:**

```
private List<ContenidoCarro> listCarro = new ArrayList<ContenidoCarro>();

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        ircarro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(Carne.this,Carro.class);
                Carne.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {
                cantidad_carro=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cantidad_carro);
                int valor=Integer.valueOf(cantidad_carro.getText().toString());
                int sumate=valor+1;

                String item = list.get(position).getNombre();
                String item2 = list.get(position).getImagen();
                int item3 = list.get(position).getValor();



                ContenidoCarro c = new ContenidoCarro();
                c.setNombre(item);
                c.setImagen(item2);
                c.setValor(item3);
                listCarro.add(c);

            }
        });
```

**Este es la clase ContenidoCarro**

```
    public class ContenidoCarro  {
    private String nombre;
    private String imagen;
    private int valor;

    public ContenidoCarro() {
    }


    public ContenidoCarro(String nombre, String imagen, int valor) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.imagen = imagen;
        this.valor = valor;
    }


    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getImagen() {
        return imagen;
    }

    public void setImagen(String imagen) {
        this.imagen = imagen;
    }

    public int getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(int valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }

}
```

Este es Carro, donde quiero recibir el `ArrayList` del 1º primer `Activity`:

```
    public class Carro extends AppCompatActivity {


    private List<ContenidoCarro> list = new ArrayList<ContenidoCarro>();
    private ListView listView;

    private AdapterCarro adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_carro);
        ArrayList<String> lista = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("listC");

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewCarro);
        adapter = new AdapterCarro(this, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido... Suponiendo que obtuviste tu medalla de informado, sabrás que añadir imagen del código no está bien. Por favor edita tu pregunta y agréga código en texto para que puedan ayudarte. Saludos.

Comment: Bienvenido, acá tienes un ejemplo de como se logra esto, enviando un `Array` de `activity` y recibirlo en un `Fragment`, también hay un ejemplo de como recibirlo desde otro `Activity`.

Comment: Hola @PROX cuando realices preguntas es importante agregar el mensaje de error, de esta forma la comunidad puede ayudarte de una mejor manera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Para que se pueda enviar tu `ArrayList` es importante que el objeto implemente la clase `Serializable` o `Parcelable`**, al parecer este es el único problema:

```
public class Dato ContenidoCarro Parcelable{
...
...
```

Enviarias el `ArrayList` de objetos mediante el Intent:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Carne.this,Carro.class);
intent.putExtra("listC", listCarro); //Agrega valores.
Carne.this.startActivity(intent);
```

y recibirias el ArrayList en la Activity destino de esta forma:

```
ArrayList<ContenidoCarro> listaDatos = (ArrayList<ContenidoCarro> ) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("listC");
```

Revisa esta pregunta relacionada:

[Guardar / Enviar información ArrayList de objetos en Intent a Activity](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64925/guardar-enviar-informaci%c3%b3n-arraylist-de-objetos-en-intent-a-activity)

Comment: gracias Elenasys