# Envio objeto a una lista dentro de Application y me la devuelve vacia

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Buenas estoy haciendo un proyecto de una tienda y a la hora de pasar un objeto a una lista en otro activity mediante la clase application, este desaparece en el camino haciendo que llegue una lista vacia. Necesito conseguir ese objeto de forma que llene la lista de un recyclerView. A continuación dejo el codigo.

**Esta es el activity que manda el objeto a application**

```
public class PantallaProd extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView tvNombre, tvPrecio, tvDescripcion;
ImageView imageView;
Button btncompra;
String pid;
String nombre;
String descripcion;
String referencia;
String marca;
double precio;
int cantidad;
int seleccion;
Toolbar toolbar;
List<Producto>productos;
Application app;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pantalla_prod);

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    app = new Application();

    productos = app.getCompras();

    Bundle datos = getIntent().getExtras();

    tvNombre = findViewById(R.id.prodNom);
    tvDescripcion = findViewById(R.id.prodDesc);
    tvPrecio = findViewById(R.id.txtPrecio);
    imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    btncompra = findViewById(R.id.btnanadir);
    if (datos != null) {
        pid = datos.getString("PID");
        nombre = datos.getString("Nombre");
        descripcion = datos.getString("Descripcion");
        precio = datos.getDouble("Precio");
        referencia = datos.getString("Referencia");
        cantidad = datos.getInt("Cantidad");
        marca = datos.getString("Marca");
    }
    tvNombre.setText(nombre);
    tvDescripcion.setText(descripcion);
    tvPrecio.setText(String.valueOf(precio));

    Glide.with(PantallaProd.this).load(referencia).into(imageView);

    btncompra.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PantallaProd.this);
           builder.setTitle("Añadir a la cesta");
           builder.setMessage("¿Quiere añadir el producto a la cesta?");
           builder.setCancelable(false);
           builder.setPositiveButton("SI", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   numberPickerDialog();
               }
           });
           builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   dialog.dismiss();
               }
           });
           builder.show();

        }
    });
}

private void numberPickerDialog(){
    NumberPicker numberPicker = new NumberPicker(this);
    numberPicker.setMaxValue(9999);
    numberPicker.setMinValue(1);
    NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener valueChangeListener = new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            seleccion=newVal;
        }
    };
    numberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(valueChangeListener);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(numberPicker);
    builder.setTitle("Cantidad");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            productos = new ArrayList<>();
            Log.e("TAG",""+seleccion);
             Producto producto = new Producto();
             producto.setNombre(nombre);
             producto.setDescripcion(descripcion);
             producto.setCantidad(seleccion);
             producto.setPid(pid);
             producto.setPrecio(precio);
             producto.setReferencia(referencia);
             producto.setMarca(marca);
             app.compras.add(producto);
             Intent intent = new Intent(PantallaProd.this, Carrito.class);
             startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}}
```

**Aquí esta mi clase Application**

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {

public List<Producto>compras = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

public List<Producto> getCompras() {
    return compras;
}

public void setCompras(List<Producto> compras) {
    this.compras = compras;
}}
```

**Por ultimo este es el activity donde recojo el objeto**

```
 Toolbar toolbar;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
AdapterCarrito adapterCarrito;
List<Producto> productos;
Application app;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_carrito);
    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    app=new Application();

    mReferencia= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerCarrito);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    productos = new ArrayList<>();
    adapterCarrito = new AdapterCarrito(app.compras);
    productos = app.getCompras();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterCarrito);

}}
```

**Este es el objeto**

```
public class Producto {
private String pid;
private String nombre;
private String descripcion;
private int cantidad;
private double precio;
private String referencia;
private String marca;



public Producto(){

}

public String getPid() {
    return pid;
}

public void setPid(String pid) {
    this.pid = pid;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}

public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public int getCantidad() {
    return cantidad;
}

public void setCantidad(int cantidad) {
    this.cantidad = cantidad;
}

public double getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}

public void setPrecio(double precio) {
    this.precio = precio;
}

public String getReferencia() {
    return referencia;
}

public void setReferencia(String referencia) {
    this.referencia = referencia;
}

public String getMarca() {
    return marca;
}

public void setMarca(String marca) {
    this.marca = marca;
}

public static List<Producto> productos(){
    List<Producto> compras = new ArrayList<>();
    return compras;
};}
```

Si alguien sabe el motivo de porque no me devuelve ningún objeto, por favor que me lo diga

Comment: Cual es la razón de la clase "Application"?, lo que debes realizar es tener un objeto "Producto"y enviar la lista de este tipo de objetos entre las Activities.

Comment: @Elenasys La razón es que era mi ultimo intento a la desesperada de conseguir realizar eso. Ya intenté usar la lista del propio objeto, pero no me dejaba de hecho, me saltaba error diciendo que recibia un null a la hora de recoger la lista

Comment: @Elenasys y aún así me sigue devolviendo una lista sin rellenar. Ya no me da el error del null pointer exception pero si que es cierto que no me recoge nada, a la hora de guardarlo, con el debugger he podido ver que si me lo guarda pero una vez cambio de pantalla se vacia sola

Comment: El problema son los objetos, deberían extender de Parcelable o Serializable , te sugiero veas esta respuesta, es lo que considero sería lo ideal a realizar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64925/guardar-enviar-informaci%c3%b3n-arraylist-de-objetos-en-intent-a-activity

Comment: @Elenasys Pues ni por esas me funciona, acabo de probar hacerlo serializable y nada

Comment: Acabo de subir la clase del objeto

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es como si cuando he hecho un recycler parecido de este objeto cargado desde firebase, porque este que lo relleno desde la pantalla anterior para hacer el carro de la compra no me imprime nada y me dice que la lista esta vacia (.size=0)

Comment: Buenas para tiendas y eso esta el LiveData de android. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMcDk2_4LSk

Comment: @OsAndNoTi Gracias, le echaré un vistazo haber si con eso consigo que me funcione todo bien